# python string slicing with a list

Tags: python, string, list, slice

Here is my list:

```
liPos = [(2,5),(8,9),(18,22)]
```

The first item of each tuple is the starting position and the second is the ending position.
Then I have a string like this:

```
s = "I hope that I will find an answer to my question!"
```

Now, considering my `liPos` list, I want to format the string by removing the chars between each starting and ending position (and including the surrounding numbers) provided in the tuples. Here is the result that I want:

```
"I tt I will an answer to my question!"
```

So basically, I want to remove the chars between 2 and 5 (including 2 and 5), then between 8,9 (including 8 and 9) and finally between 18,22 (including 18 and 22).

Any suggestion?

Comment: did you make a mistake in your desired answer? given your liPos, shouldn't it be "I  tt I will an answer to my question!" ?

Comment: lol yeah, sorry I made a mistake, but I edited it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
liPos = [(2,5),(8,9),(18,22)]
s = "I hope that I will find an answer to my question!"

exclusions = set().union(* (set(range(t[0], t[1]+1)) for t in liPos) )
pruned = ''.join(c for i,c in enumerate(s) if i not in exclusions)

print pruned
```

Answer (score 5):

This assumes that `liPos` is already sorted, if it is not used `sorted(liPos, reverse=True)` in the `for` loop.

```
liPos = [(2,5),(8,9),(18,22)]
s = "I hope that I will find an answer to my question!"
for begin, end in reversed(liPos):
    s = s[:begin] + s[end+1:]

print s
```

Here is an alternative method that constructs a new list of slice tuples to include, and then joining the string with only those included portions.

```
from itertools import chain, izip_longest
# second slice index needs to be increased by one, do that when creating liPos
liPos = [(a, b+1) for a, b in liPos]
result = "".join(s[b:e] for b, e in izip_longest(*[iter(chain([0], *liPos))]*2))
```

To make this slightly easier to understand, here are the slices generated by `izip_longest`:

```
>>> list(izip_longest(*[iter(chain([0], *liPos))]*2))
[(0, 2), (6, 8), (10, 18), (23, None)]
```

Comment: I have a large string and it fails to the print the source as I want. Though I haven't tried your second met yet.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one, compact possibility:

```
"".join(s[i] for i in range(len(s)) if not any(start <= i <= end for start, end in liPos))
```

Answer (score 2):

This ... is a quick stab at the problem.  There may be a better way, but it's a start at least.

```
>>> liPos = [(2,5),(8,9),(18,22)]
>>>
>>> toRemove = [i for x, y in liPos for i in range(x, y + 1)]
>>>
>>> toRemove
[2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]
>>>
>>> s = "I hope that I will find an answer to my question!"
>>>
>>> s2 = ''.join([c for i, c in enumerate(s) if i not in toRemove])
>>>
>>> s2
'I  tt I will an answer to my question!'
```

Comment: There are some obvious shortcomings to this approach.  The first is that it will be _slow_ for large lists of indexes to remove.  That could be sped up with a different container type for `toRemove`.  It may also use more memory than necessary, though changing the parameter passed to `''.join()` from a list `[]` to a generator `()` would help with that.